# WP REST API v2: Getting posts by post ids

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get all posts by ID's using WP REST API. As per the documentation, we can use filter to use WP Query arguments. Using this with posts end point returns all the posts.

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[posts__in]=470,469
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the v2 of WP REST API use this format-

`http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include[]=470&include[]=469`

If you want custom coding then,

You can retrieve single post by id like

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[p]=470
```

But as per support its will not work for multiple post.

```
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1368
```

So you can ran a loop and get one by one.

But for multiple you have to put an function

```
add_filter('rest_query_vars', 'custom_rest_query_vars');
function custom_rest_query_vars($query_vars) {
  $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars,    array('post','post__in','type','id') );
  return $query_vars;
}
```

Then you have to run

```
+filter[post__in][]=470&filter[post__in][]=469
```

Comment: I'm new to WordPress development but know bit of PHP. Where do I need to add this code?

Comment: The `add_filter` command should be inserted inside the `functions.php` file of your WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 26):

With V2 This is working for me, more butter then adding custom code

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include[]=470&include[]=469
```

An other way is to compose the query like this:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=470,469
```

Comment: No need to use two `?includes`, you can use:
`http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include[469,470]`

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**

The **easiest and fastest** way is this

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id>
```

more information [developer wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#definition-example-request)

Answer (score -1):

I want to add with the current answer above. To retrieve a single post form outside through API you can use

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/450
```

where Post ID  = 450.